# how to remove wordpress site error "missing author missing updates"?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on wordpress. and when checking in webmaster tool these error displayed.
**missing author missing updates** ?HOw to remove these errors?

Answer (score 0):

On your Template Click Edit HTML.
    Now using Google Chromes press Ctrl+F to find the code "timestamp-link". Skip the first code you'll find, Stop the second code you'll find, like below:

```
     <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='published' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>

Now  change it to the code below code :

    <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='updated published' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>
```